# Sync pictures of iPhone with Mac

Tags: macos, ios, camera

How can I sync the pictures from my iPhone (5, iOS 6) to the Mac (OS X 10.8.2) (but not vice versa) via WiFi but without going through the cloud? In case it matters, I am using iPhoto on the Mac.

Comment: I don't know of a Wi-Fi solution, but tethered via USB there are many apps to manage this. On the Mac, I'd start with [PadSync](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/padsync/)

Comment: The tethered solution for me is iPhoto, which works pretty well.

Comment: Hmm - so you just import them in iPhoto rather than using PhotoStream or the Image Capture app?

Comment: Yes, because PhotoStream goes through the cloud.

Answer (score -2):

Connect the phone to the Mac. Launch iPhoto. Click import.

Comment: They did specify Wifi sync, which implies no cord.

Comment: Dead right they did, I misread. Apologies